# Eigenvalues of the Laplacian and min-max formula in any space dimension

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, semigroups-of-operators

In which reference book can I find a proof that the eigenvalue of the Laplace operator in a domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^d$ with $d \ge 1$  are given by
$$
\lambda_1 = \min_{u \in H^1_0(\Omega), \| u \|_{L^2(\Omega) = 1}} \| \nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
$$
$$
\lambda_k = \min_{u \in K_{k+1}, \| u \|_{L^2(\Omega) = 1}} \| \nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
$$
where $K_{k+1} = \{u \in H^1_0: (u,e_j)_{H^1_0} = 0 \forall j = 1, \dots, k\}$ and $e_j$ denotes the eigenfunction corresponding to $\lambda_j$?

This should be a classical result, but I'm only aware of references where such min-max formula is proved for matrices. Also, is it true that it holds for any space dimension $d \in \mathbb N$ including $d=1$?

Comment: The proof of this is given for more general divergence-form operators in Gilbarg and Trudinger's book. (Technically they prove the first of the two and then explain why the other can be proved along similar lines.) In my edition this is in Section 8.12 'The eigenvalue problem', pages 212-214.

Comment: This holds for any semibounded self-adjoint operator. The version you quote is the one for quadratic forms. Standard books for this kind of material are Reed-Simon and Kato.

Comment: @LeoMoos Thanks! But in that proof they use the Sobolev compact embedding into $L^2$, which makes sense for $d \ge 2$. How do you get the case $d=1$?

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you. Do you know if the references you mention also cover the case $d=1$?

Comment: @user173196: There is no $d$ in the general framework, the result is about a general semibounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space.

Comment: Yes, it is classical: this is written in Hilbert Courant, vol I, Chapter 6 sections 1-2.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I don't see the min-max formula in that Chapter. Can you give me a page number (and the edition of the book)?

Comment: @ChristianRemling What replaces the Sobolev embedding in that context?

Comment: @user173196: I use First English edition, John Wiley and sons, NY, Copyright 1953, reprint 1989. Chapter VI, section 1, page 399. He writes your formula partially with words, instead of a single formula.